# When are brackets required for pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Using this code :

```
-- Store a person's name, age, and favourite Thing.
data Person = Person String Int Thing
  deriving Show

brent :: Person
brent = Person "Brent" 31 SealingWax

stan :: Person
stan  = Person "Stan" 94 Cabbage

getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge (Person _ a _) = a
```

to access age of stan use :

```
getAge stan
```

prints : 
94

Defining stan does not require brackets.

However `getAge Person "a" 1 Cabbage` causes error :

```
<interactive>:60:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `Person'
                with actual type `String -> Int -> Thing -> Person'
    Probable cause: `Person' is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of `getAge', namely `Person'
    In the expression: getAge Person "a" 1 Cabbage
```

I need to use brackets :

```
*Main> getAge (Person "a" 1 Cabbage)
1
```

Why are brackets required in this case ? But when defining `stan  = Person "Stan" 94 Cabbage` does not require brackets ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getAge Person "a" 1 Cabbage
```

is parsed as

```
(((getAge Person) "a") 1) Cabbage
```

i.e. this would have to be a function accepting a `Person`-*constructor* and three more arguments, not a function accepting a single `Person`-*value*.

Why it's [done this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)? Well, it makes multi-parameter functions much nicer. For instance, `Person` itself is a function, taking three arguments (the data type's fields). If Haskell didn't just feed arguments one-by-one, you would also need to write `Person ("Brent", 31, Sealingwax)`.

The parsing rules Haskell uses are actually much simpler than in most other languages, and they allow *partial application* very naturally, which is really useful. For instance,

> GHCi> map (Person "Brent" 31) [Cabbage, SealingWax]
>   [Person "Brent" 31 Cabbage, Person "Brent" 31 SealingWax]